# How to define names and number of columns in Data Frame based on value of parameter of fucntion in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I have my own build function in Python Pandas like below (but it is obviously only sample):

```
def my_function(x):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=x)
```

And I need to make something like that for example:

- if parameter x is 4 then names of columns are: "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4" and there are 4 columns
- if parameter x is 2 then names of columns are: "col1", "col2" and there are 2 columns

So name of columns (col...) and number of columns have to be depend on value of parameter x of this function.

How can I do that? How to modify this function to achieve it in Python Pandas?

Comment: if you don't mind upvoting my answer would be appreciated as it got downvoted without reason

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use:

```
def my_function(x):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'col%s' % (i+1): [] for i in range(x)})
```

Comment: Great it works!, but what means "s" in 'col%s...." ? I see that without this "s" it does not works ?

Comment: This is to format the string '%s' gets replaced by the number. You can read this: https://pyformat.info/